# Calculate total earnings while looping between two points of time every 15 minutes

Tags: php, loops, hour

I am really stuck on the code, and I dont know how to solve it. I am trying to calculate how much I earn a day. The problem is that I earn different amount depending on which hour on a day it is. Fx:

```
08.00 - 06.00  (Morning) -> 150
06.00 - 10.00 (Evening) -> 200
10.00 - 11.00 (Night) -> 250
```

So I have calculated how much hours I work a day with this code:

```
<p>Choose Your Work TIme</p>
    <form method='post'>
        <select name="s1" required>
        <option>Choose Start Time</option>
            <option value="8.45">8.45</option>
            <option value="9.00">9.00</option>
            <option value="9.15">9.15</option>
            <option value="9.30">9.30</option>
            <option value="9.45">9.45</option>
            <option value="10.00">10.00</option>
            <option value="10.15">10.15</option>
            <option value="10.30">10.30</option>
            <option value="10.45">10.45</option>
            <option value="11.00">11.00</option>
            <option value="11.15">11.15</option>
            <option value="11.30">11.30</option>
            <option value="11.45">11.45</option>
            <option value="12.00">12.00</option>
            <option value="12.15">12.15</option>
            <option value="12.30">12.30</option>
            <option value="12.45">12.45</option>
            <option value="13.00">13.00</option>
            <option value="13.15">13.15</option>
            <option value="13.30">13.30</option>
            <option value="13.45">13.45</option>
            <option value="14.00">14.00</option>
            <option value="14.15">14.15</option>
            <option value="14.30">14.30</option>
            <option value="14.45">14.45</option>
            <option value="15.00">15.00</option>
            <option value="15.15">15.15</option>
            <option value="15.30">15.30</option>
            <option value="15.45">15.45</option>
            <option value="16.00">16.00</option>
            <option value="16.15">16.15</option>
            <option value="16.30">16.30</option>
            <option value="16.45">16.45</option>
            <option value="17.00">17.00</option>
            <option value="17.15">17.15</option>
            <option value="17.30">17.30</option>
            <option value="17.45">17.45</option>
            <option value="18.00">18.00</option>
            <option value="18.15">18.15</option>
            <option value="18.30">18.30</option>
            <option value="18.45">18.45</option>
            <option value="19.00">19.00</option>
            <option value="19.15">19.15</option>
            <option value="19.30">19.30</option>
            <option value="19.45">19.45</option>
            <option value="20.00">20.00</option>
            <option value="20.15">20.15</option>
            <option value="20.30">20.30</option>
            <option value="20.45">20.45</option>
            <option value="21.00">21.00</option>
            <option value="21.15">21.15</option>
            <option value="21.30">21.30</option>
            <option value="21.45">21.45</option>
            <option value="22.00">22.00</option>
            <option value="22.15">22.15</option>
            <option value="22.30">22.30</option>
            <option value="22.45">22.45</option>
            <option value="23.00">23.00</option>
            <option value="23.15">23.15</option>
            <option value="23.30">23.30</option>
        </select>
        <select name="s2" required>
            <option>Choose End Time</option>
            <option value="8.45">8.45</option>
            <option value="9.00">9.00</option>
            <option value="9.15">9.15</option>
            <option value="9.30">9.30</option>
            <option value="9.45">9.45</option>
            <option value="10.00">10.00</option>
            <option value="10.15">10.15</option>
            <option value="10.30">10.30</option>
            <option value="10.45">10.45</option>
            <option value="11.00">11.00</option>
            <option value="11.15">11.15</option>
            <option value="11.30">11.30</option>
            <option value="11.45">11.45</option>
            <option value="12.00">12.00</option>
            <option value="12.15">12.15</option>
            <option value="12.30">12.30</option>
            <option value="12.45">12.45</option>
            <option value="13.00">13.00</option>
            <option value="13.15">13.15</option>
            <option value="13.30">13.30</option>
            <option value="13.45">13.45</option>
            <option value="14.00">14.00</option>
            <option value="14.15">14.15</option>
            <option value="14.30">14.30</option>
            <option value="14.45">14.45</option>
            <option value="15.00">15.00</option>
            <option value="15.15">15.15</option>
            <option value="15.30">15.30</option>
            <option value="15.45">15.45</option>
            <option value="16.00">16.00</option>
            <option value="16.15">16.15</option>
            <option value="16.30">16.30</option>
            <option value="16.45">16.45</option>
            <option value="17.00">17.00</option>
            <option value="17.15">17.15</option>
            <option value="17.30">17.30</option>
            <option value="17.45">17.45</option>
            <option value="18.00">18.00</option>
            <option value="18.15">18.15</option>
            <option value="18.30">18.30</option>
            <option value="18.45">18.45</option>
            <option value="19.00">19.00</option>
            <option value="19.15">19.15</option>
            <option value="19.30">19.30</option>
            <option value="19.45">19.45</option>
            <option value="20.00">20.00</option>
            <option value="20.15">20.15</option>
            <option value="20.30">20.30</option>
            <option value="20.45">20.45</option>
            <option value="21.00">21.00</option>
            <option value="21.15">21.15</option>
            <option value="21.30">21.30</option>
            <option value="21.45">21.45</option>
            <option value="22.00">22.00</option>
            <option value="22.15">22.15</option>
            <option value="22.30">22.30</option>
            <option value="22.45">22.45</option>
            <option value="23.00">23.00</option>
            <option value="23.15">23.15</option>
            <option value="23.30">23.30</option>
        </select>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" Value="Submit">
    </form>
```

Lets say I work from 10.00 in the morning to 11.00 in the night. That would mean I work 13 hours. But how can i calculate how much money I earn in the above time period? I have tried the following but nothing is working:

```
<?php


// create timeblocks:
// 8  = from 0.00 untill 8.00 
// 18 = from 8.00 untill 18.00
// 24 = from 18.00 untill 0.00
$timeblocks=array(
    8*60,
    18*60,
    24*60
    );
//earnings PER 15 MINUTES in the above timeblocks
$money=array(
    146/4,
    204/4,
    244/4
    );
$earned=0;

//create a start and end time object
$start=date_create_from_format('Y-m-d H:i:s', $_POST['s1']);
$end=date_create_from_format('Y-m-d H:i:s', $_POST['s2']);

//calculate how many blocks of 15 minutes
$diff=$start->diff($end);
$steps=(($diff->d)*3600+($diff->h)*60+($diff->i))/15;

//loop every 15 minutes
for($i=0;$i<=$steps;$i++){
    //start with the start date, and add 15 minutes every time
    if($i!==0)$start->add(new DateInterval('PT15M'));

    //calculate the time 
    $time=((int)($start->format('H')*60)+(int)($start->format('i')));

    //look in timeblocks what block we are in and get the earnings from that block
    for($block=0;$block<3;$block++){
        if($time<=$timeblocks[$block]){
            $earned+=$money[$block];
            echo '$'.$money[$block].' earned at '.$start->format('d-m-Y H:i:s').'<br>';
            break;
            }
        }
    }

echo 'TOTAL earned: $'.$earned; 


?>
```

I hope somebody can help me.

Best Regards
Mads

Comment: Last time I checked, you work 13 hours when you start at 10 in the morning till 11 in the evening...

Comment: You have a mistake very early on by assuming `$hours_worked = $end_time - $start_time;` - that is incorrect. 12.30-11.45 will return 0.85, but it is actually 45 minutes. You need to convert your times into timestamps. You can use any day you like, such as `$starttime = strtotime('2015-01-01 '.$_POST['starttime']);` (assuming you format starttime with a colon instead of a period).

Comment: thanks for the answers. Something like this?

$to_time = strtotime($_POST['s2']);
$from_time = strtotime($_POST['s1']);


echo (round(abs($to_time - $from_time) / 60,2)/60). " hour";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure there are better solutions, but this works :-)

**[edit]** to meet OP's new requirements

```
//If you haven't done allready SET your timezone!!
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Amsterdam');

// create timeblocks:
// 8  = from 0.00 untill 8.00 
// 18 = from 8.00 untill 18.00
// 24 = from 18.00 untill 0.00
$timeblocks=array(
    8*60,
    18*60,
    24*60
    );
//earnings PER 15 MINUTES in the above timeblocks
$money=array(
    100/4,
    10/4,
    50/4
    );
$earned=0;

$_POST['s1']='18.30';
$_POST['s2']='8.30';

//sanitize your post: only numbers and a dot allowed
$s1=preg_replace("/[^0-9|.]/","",$_POST['s1']);
$s2=preg_replace("/[^0-9|.]/","",$_POST['s2']);

if($s1==$s2){
    //no working time: do something
    //NOTE: this assumes nobody working for 24 hours, because if you start at 
    //6pm day 1 and end 6pm on the next day (==24 hours) the times are the same 
    //as well.
    }

//if second time smaller then first time, we are in the next day and add 24 hours
$add=0;
if($s1>$s2)$add=24;

//make hours and minutes
$s1=explode('.',substr('0'.$s1,-5));
$s2=explode('.',substr('0'.$s2,-5));

//create a start and end time object
$start=new Datetime('now');
$start->setTime($s1[0],$s1[1]);

$end=new Datetime('now');
$end->setTime($s2[0]+$add,$s2[1]);


//calculate how many blocks of 15 minutes
$diff=$start->diff($end);
$steps=(($diff->d)*3600+($diff->h)*60+($diff->i))/15;

//loop every 15 minutes
for($i=1;$i<=$steps;$i++){
    //start with the start date, and add 15 minutes every time
    $start->add(new DateInterval('PT15M'));

    //calculate the time 
    $time=((int)($start->format('H')*60)+(int)($start->format('i')));

    //look in timeblocks what block we are in and get the earnings from that block
    for($block=0;$block<3;$block++){
        if($time<=$timeblocks[$block]){
            $earned+=$money[$block];
            echo '$'.$money[$block].' earned at '.$start->format('d-m-Y H:i:s').'<br>';
            break;
            }
        }
    }

echo 'TOTAL earned: $'.$earned;
```

Comment: Hello Michel. Thanks you so much for your answer. It defiantly gave something to work with. I have just edited my question, with some of your code. I need to take my input from s1 and s2, so I am thinking of : //create a start and end time object
$start=date_create_from_format('Y-m-d H:i:s', $_POST['s1']);
$end=date_create_from_format('Y-m-d H:i:s', $_POST['s2']);

Comment: Note that I also adjusted the loop at the end slightly. It now starts at 1 and skipps the starttime.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your time Michel. When I run the script with my html code, it just give me a blank page. Dont use more time on it, you used a lot of time already. But thanks a lot for your time and answer :)

Comment: No problem. Glad I could help. The new code runs fine here, so there have to be some other problem in your page.

Comment: Yes there must have been some kind of problem. I just have to ask you one specifik thing. The code is running fine, but it dosent take my input for s1 and s2, but print out from 18.45 to 8.30. I would guess it is because of the : $_POST['s1']='18.30';
$_POST['s2']='8.30';
or?
Best Regards, Mads

Comment: Yes of course, you'll have to remove those lines, they overwrite your original values :-)

Comment: Pipes do not mean "or" within a character class.

Answer (score 1):

```
$begin = new DateTime( 'YYYY-MM-DD h:I' );
$end = new DateTime( 'YYYY-MM-DD h:I' );


$interval = new DateInterval('P1I');
$daterange = new DatePeriod($begin, $interval ,$end);

foreach($daterange as $date){
    //each of the hours in between.
    //do the checks on the hour here $date will be the variable your interested in
}
```

I would suggest using the date time, Hours get more complex when DST etc come in to play also when crossing midnight

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Maybe it is a good idea with datetime. Later on I also have to use, to browse through 2 dates. Inside the foreach loop, should I make some if/else statements?

Comment: or a switch, or even a function call

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier to change your HTML code replacing your "dot-minutes" values with .25, .5 and .75 in the `value` attribute of each `option` tag. For instance :

```
 <option value="13.75">13:45</option>
```

The following PHP code will then do what you are expecting

Your original code:

```
<?php 

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    echo "Started time : " . $_POST['s1'] . "<br/>";
    echo "End time : " . $_POST['s2'] . "<br/>" ;

    $start_time = $_POST['s1'];
    $end_time = $_POST['s2'];

    $early_time_salary = 150;
    $middle_time_salary = 200;
    $late_time_salary = 250;
```

Code to add

```
 $hour0=$end_time-$start_time;
 if ($hour0>0) {
   $hour1=($end_time>18) ? $end_time-18 : 0;
   $hour2=($end_time>22) ? $end_time-22 : 0;

   $tot=($hour0*150) + $hour1*50 + $hour2*50;

   echo "Total earned: $tot";
 } else {
   echo "Error : work finished before it starts";
 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. But the code is not running:-/. But it is true with the values. I did not think about that. I will correct it :)

Comment: The code work inserted in your original code. As you edited your post since I wrote my answer, I have edited to show your original code to be included.

Answer (score 0):

I would approach it this way:

1. Create a lookup array with elements for each time-based pay change.
2. Create a DateTime Period to iterate every 15 minutes between the two passed in times.
3. As you iterate each 15-minute interval, calculate the correct pay and add that amount to your total.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/7vUUF))

```
$_POST['s1'] = '16.15';
$_POST['s2'] = '23.30';

$wagesLookup = [
    '18:00' => 146 / 4,  // morning
    '22:00' => 204 / 4,  // evening
    '24:00' => 244 / 4   // night
];

$period = new DatePeriod(
     DateTime::createFromFormat('H.i', $_POST['s1']),
     new DateInterval('PT15M'),
     DateTime::createFromFormat('H.i:01', "{$_POST['s2']}:01")  // bump ahead to make "inclusive"
);

$total = 0;
foreach ($period as $dt) {
    $time = $dt->format('H:i');
    foreach ($wagesLookup as $mark => $pay) {
        if ($time <= $mark) {
            break;
        }
    }
    printf("%s earned %.02f\n", $dt->format('H:i'), $pay);
    $total += $pay;
}
echo "Total: $total";
```

Output:

```
16:15 earned 36.50
16:30 earned 36.50
16:45 earned 36.50
17:00 earned 36.50
17:15 earned 36.50
17:30 earned 36.50
17:45 earned 36.50
18:00 earned 36.50
18:15 earned 51.00
18:30 earned 51.00
18:45 earned 51.00
19:00 earned 51.00
19:15 earned 51.00
19:30 earned 51.00
19:45 earned 51.00
20:00 earned 51.00
20:15 earned 51.00
20:30 earned 51.00
20:45 earned 51.00
21:00 earned 51.00
21:15 earned 51.00
21:30 earned 51.00
21:45 earned 51.00
22:00 earned 51.00
22:15 earned 61.00
22:30 earned 61.00
22:45 earned 61.00
23:00 earned 61.00
23:15 earned 61.00
Total: 1413
```